# Backbone jquery-mobile app - is jqm still worth using without using changepage

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, mobile, backbone.js

I have started building an app using backbone and jquery mobile.
I wanted the jqm for its widgets and CSS styling, and also used its "changepage method", because it allowed me to use CSS3 transitions, and backbone didn't.

I've discovered this plugin [backbone CSS3 transitions](https://github.com/techjacker/Backbone-Responsive-CSS3-Page-Transitions)

I'm wondering if it is worth it to use jquery pagechange, and if not, if it is still useful to use jQM's JS at all, and not only the jquery CSS.

**What would jqm javascript be useful for if I have CSS3 page transitions in backbone router and jqm CSS for styling ?**

Comment: jQM styles requires jQM js. If you dont want jQM widgets (js), then you better off not using jQM js all together.

Comment: You mention that you want to use JQM for it's widgets and css styling, that would seem to be a good reason to use it even if you aren't using it for transitions. As a side point you might find it easier to use one of the *routers* available for JQM instead of the backbone.js router and just use backbone.js for your structure.